# Why we give permissions to Lambda while fetching Kinesis Stream and not the other way around?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis

I have a lambda which fetches data from Kinesis stream. When assigning the permissions, we give the lambda execution role a policy to access Kinesis stream. But, we don't give any permission to Kinesis that it allows that lambda the permission to get data from it? Why is it so?

Similarly, lambda with Dynamodb is the similar case. But when we do integrate lambda with Api gateway, in this case, we add permission to lambda that API gateway can invoke it.

I wanted to understand the basic concept of IAM permissions and roles which would define which resource we should give permissions and which one we shouldn't. I am quite naive while knowing these concepts of IAM. Any explanation on this thing you can give would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda execution role grants it permission to access necessary AWS services and resources. Lambda will assume the role during execution.

That is why, as you mentioned, you give Kinesis (or) DynamoDB permissions because you perform operations on these services within lambda

However, the permission you add for API Gateway is a resource based policy to allow an API Gateway (or any AWS service) to invoke your function.

Reference: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-permissions.html